# How to structure webdev folders so that site doesn't get indexed by Google?

Tags: php, seo

How do I structure my web development environment so that Search Engines don't index my projects?

I am working on a number of projects for different customers and each customer's site is located at www.mydomain.com/webdev/des1, www.mydomain.com/webdev/des2, www.mydomain.com/webdev/des3 etc.

I structured it this way however I went on google today and realised that it has been indexing  customer's websites that are in development and therefore are not ready to be launched.

What can I do to remove those websites from google results until they are finished and how to I structure my dev environment so that it doesn't happen in future? I am sorry to ask 2 questions here but I really need urgent advice from someone who has made the same mistake.

Comment: RTLM: http://www.robotstxt.org/   and if it's in development, you should have it PW protected anyways. never level 'in dev' stuff open to the public.

Comment: @MarcB thanks for your reply. Could you please explain what you mean by the first part regarding robotstxt.org? what do I need to do? Also, where should I move everything to?

Comment: The `R` stands for **READ**...

Comment: @MarcB could you add the first comment as an answer so I can select it as the correct answer please? Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Disallow access for all robots on all pages
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

But as allready said it will only block robots and only those robots whom obey the robots.txt protocoll. And even though you blocked the google bot with this, your URL still may get indexed in the search engine, though no title or description will be seen in the snippet. However as allready suggested you should use some sort of password protection.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I structure my web development environment so that Search Engines don't index my projects?

By not allowing public (anonymous/guest) access.

In your case by accident you have already launched those websites. Now you can try to contact google so that they remove it from their index again. They will also tell you how you can prevent that in the future. It is part of their help pages. Look for *webmaster resources*.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not the ideal fix but in order to make the website inaccessible I have used a plugin that doesn't let people access the website. I will use this approach until I restructure my web dev environment for current and future projects. Thanks everyone for their help and advice